Is any better way to handle event type in React Typescript?
 const typeHandler = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {

    if ((e.target as HTMLButtonElement).tagName === "BUTTON") {
      const selectedType: string = (e.target as HTMLButtonElement).innerText
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(" ", "_");

      setType(selectedType);
    }
}

this how i handle my event and my button type, i am looking for a better way or more modular way to handle this.

Create a custom React hook to encapsulate the logic for handling button clicks. This hook can take parameters like a callback function to be executed with the button's content.
Hook:
function useButtonHandler(callback: (type: string) => void) {
  return <T extends HTMLElement>(e: React.MouseEvent<T>) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    if (target && target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      const selectedType = target.innerText.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_");
      callback(selectedType);
    }
  };
}

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const handleType = (type: string) => {
    console.log(`Type selected: ${type}`);
    // Perform further actions based on type
  };

  const handleClick = useButtonHandler(handleType);

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
  );
};

